# How would I prove this indirectly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

If $x + z > 80$ then $x > 40$ or $z > 40$.

Proof by contrapositive:

Written contrapositive:
If $x \le 40$ and $z \le 40$ then $x + z \le 80$.

Let $x = 40$ and $z = 40$, then
$x+z \le 80$.

My question is, would I need to now prove for all $x$ and $y$ values less than or equal to $40$? Is there a better way to write this or is just stating what I have written enough?

Answer (score 2):

That's enough.

It's also enough to say if $x \le 40$ then $x+y > 80 \implies y > 80 - x \ge 80-40 = 40$.  So either $x > 40$ or if it is not, then $y > 0$.

Alternatively $avg(x,y) = \frac {x+y}2 > \frac {80}2 = 40$ and you can't have *both* $x,y$ be below average.

And if you want to shoot a housefly with a bow and arrow:

Let $d= \max(x,y)-\min(x,y) \ge 0$ so $\min(x,y) = \min(x,y) -d$.

So $x+ y = \min(x,y) + \max(x,y) = 2\max(x,y) - d > 80$ so $\max (x,y) > 40 +\frac d2 \ge 40$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easiest way to handle this style of inequality question is first to represent your variables as an inequality on $0$. Here: $$x\leq 40 \to x=40-p, p\geq 0; z\leq 40 \to z=40-q, q\geq 0$$

In this way, we have that $$x+z=80-(p+q)\leq80$$
because $p,q\geq 0\implies p+q\geq 0$. In this way, the step $x\leq 40, z\leq 40 \implies x+z\leq 80$ is better justified.

As a matter of proof of the original statement, the contrapositive works totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is immediate from the contrapositive.  Just add up the two inequalities.  You don't need anything after that.